# How do you make steel weapons and armor in Dwarf Fortress Masterwork Mod?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, mods

In the Masterwork Mod for Dwarf Fortress, there are lots of new buildings and some old buildings disappeared. The manual says that weapons are made at "Forge". How do you build a forge in Masterwork? It doesn't show up on the list of forges if you press b-e.

I've tried building about half the other forge buildings, and so far still can't make steel weapons or armor. The only weapons the dorfs have made are wooden crossbows at the Bowyer's Workshop, and stone war hammers at the Stoneforge. The Weaponry can "upgrade" a stone war hammer.

But which building makes the simple metal weapons, armor, and ammo in Masterwork? I want to make steel war hammers, steel crossbows, steel bolts, and steel armor. Currently it's up to winter and the fortress is looking pretty dooomed due to lack of this necessary equipment.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at the [building list](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Category:Masterwork:Buildings) for Masterwork and there's no mention of a specific Forge. So, I'll assume that the vanilla DF [Forge](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Metalsmith%27s_forge) is *the way* to make items out of Steel, even in Masterwork.

In order to build a Forge, you need to have an Anvil, which is included in the default embark. To build a Forge, you press <kbd>b</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> at the Main Menu.

The problem, I feel, lies elsewhere. In order to produce Steel objects, you need to have Steel Bars. And the process behind Steel bar manufacturing is extensive. You can check it [here](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Steel#Recipe).

(Disclaimer: I don't play Masterwork, I might be missing certain details)